# How to use SignalR-Client-Cpp library for QTC++ android project?

Tags: android, c++, windows, qt

I am developing a QTC++ android app that needs to communicate with an ASP.NET Core SignalR server. I want to use the SignalR-Client-Cpp library (https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp) as the client for my app, but I am not sure how to integrate it with my project for android.
I am using Qt 6.5.2 .

Comment: If you want to deploy signalR to a mobile app you need to rethink your architecture.